# Numbers - multiple conditions in an if statement

Tags: numbers

I am trying to do this:

`IF(day(now()) > 28 and day(now()) < 1, A1 + B1, A2 + B2)`

However this gives a syntax error. Is it not possible to have more than one operation in a condition?

I don't want to have nested `IFs` because the other calculations are more complicated than the example and I don't want to have to duplicate the entire thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IF(AND(day(now()) > 28,day(now()) < 1), A1 + B1, A2 + B2)
```

The full user guide is available [here](https://support.apple.com/numbers).

Comment: Thank you, that was the syntax I needed